# Phone's battery is draining unusually fast even when not in use

Tags: battery, charging, task-management, oneplus-one

The hardware I'm using:

- OnePlus One, bought late december 2014
- Stock Cyanogenmod, version 12.1 - YOG4PAS1N0 (= Android 5.1.1)
- no apps to improve battery life in any way

Basically, the battery is just draining without any obviously strenuous activity. Previously, I would have competitions with a fellow OP1 user about who could push their battery life beyond the 3 day threshold. Now I go to work fully charged, the battery drops by 10% while I'm still on the 45min train ride to work and I return home with single digits or an empty battery.

After having a look at the battery stats I noticed this:

[image: Battery-General]

During work, I turned the screen on and off periodically to check WhatsApp and a little Fallout:Shelter (5min) on the loo but beyond that nothing happened. Screen battery usage was at 6%, so that can't be it.

Details for "Email" (Email, app version 2.6.1 (237), Boxer Inc):

- CPU total/foreground: 2h 16m 30s / 52s
- Keep awake: 1h 55m 54s
- Mobile packets received/sent: 1655/1985
- Mobile radio active: 53m 2s
- Wi-Fi packets received/sent: 58/68

Details for "Android OS":

- CPU total: 2h 3m 12s
- Keep awake: 23m 48s
- Mobile packets received/sent: 3293/3039
- Mobile radio active: 1h 1m 15s
- Wi-Fi packets received/sent: 293/282

Does anybody have a clue what's going on here? Because I'm straight out of ideas after checking if the Boxer Email has a recurring memory leak, restarting the phone, looking for a way to disable syncing the entire email archive in the app (who knows, might just be it) or testing if it is caused by push synchronisation...

Comment: See this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125070/126899 I'm fairly sure it's the same situation.