# Battery Issue with Android 6.0

Tags: battery, battery-life, 6.0-marshmallow

I upgraded my Karbonn Sparkle V to Android 6.0 recently. after a couple of days the battery drains quickly. hence charging the phone also takes hours. this was not at all a issue when it had lollipop 5.1.1.

yesterday the battery was 54% at night 12:00. closed the web browser, all apps, locked the phone as usual and slept but in the morning when I saw it had 4% battery remaining.

when I saw battery settings morning 4 new menus displayed, apart from display(6% usage) and chrome(4% usage), viz. Phone Idle, Wi-Fi, Android OS, mobile signal. they all used 1% of battery each. what might be the problem. Wi-Fi was always on from the day1 of purchasing the phone no issues at that time. only now issue arises. what might be the problem?

and I saw this post([Android 6.0 drains my Nexus 5 battery within an hour](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125847/android-6-0-drains-my-nexus-5-battery-within-an-hour)).
It only changes settings and display like a new one but battery issue is same.

Comment: Do you use any apps to display the battery percentage in the status bar?

Comment: no.I used some battery monitors for a day but they show the same thing that the phones battery menu shows. btw the battery percentage is already displayed in the drag down menu na.

Comment: Okay. I want to confirm that you are using the system readings of the battery percentage for the reference. Because third party apps may not always show correct percentages.

Comment: this user seems to have same problem-(http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125070/spotting-cause-of-excessive-battery-drain)

Comment: @Lucky I've found the exact opposite to be true. For me, the system battery monitor is terribly inaccurate and GSam battery monitor is far more reasonable. ( I don't think with 2 1/2 hours of screen use it's only 1% of my battery for the day)

Comment: @Vishu I've seen a few of these already. Nearly all of them were wakelock issues. Check and see if the "awake" section of the battery graph is just a flat on bar.

Comment: @Ethan Z ---YES!!!! I was goin to ask the same. I saw the battery graph awake bar was complete green. i.e,it(Awake) was active all the time

Comment: @ Ethan Z -  awake section in battery graph is always green( fully active-flat on bar) If you know a way out Please Reply!!

Comment: @Vishu is your device rooted?

Comment: No it is not rooted. My device is karbonn sparkle V.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30367/discussion-between-vishu-and-ethan-z).

Answer (score 2):

The Marshmallow 6.0.1 update seems to have solved this battery drain problem.

Source: [AndroidPit](https://www.androidpit.com/forum/671191/my-battery-draining-fast-after-marshmallow-update/page/5)

2 users have confirmed it in that link. Please check.

Comment: Yes! the battery life is much better after the 6.0.1 update.Thank you!

Comment: Even I have updated my Karbonn Sparkle V to 6.0.1. The battery backup is much better than what it was with Android L.

Comment: Welcome. I am happy my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I write here, use app named wakelock detector, and there give a look what is always ON. Sometimes this is problem with custom roms, or like in my situation phone doesn't go to sleep coz of some widget. You obviosly have problem with deep sleep...

Comment: For this case, IMO, link for the app, a brief description and use-case (optionally: screenshots) for the goal is required for this answer to be  considered detailed. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: How can I overcome this deep sleep problem. Wakelock is asking to be installed as a system app should I do it?

Comment: "You obviosly have problem with deep sleep..." did you mean that my phone is not going to deep sleep when not being used? my device is always awake as it shows in the battery graph. If you cant answer then please lets chat. Welcome!

Comment: Hit yes, but I think your phone must be rooted. Also did you tried wiping cache, andd dalvik from recovery, someone had this same problem after upgrading to M, also you can try factory reset..

Comment: Nope!My device is not rooted.wakelock needs rooted phones to be installed into na.hence i am unable to give it root access which it is asking for.I tried cleaning cache but not working. I didn't try factory reset.and what do mean by "add dalvik from recovery". Do you mean to install dalvik cache cleaner? Thanks for the response! As you said my device is not going into deepsleep when it should be doing so.

Comment: Hmm, did u tried manually clean per-app  cache, from settings? I've tought you have custom recovery, but obviosly you don't have it, so I don't know how to clear dalvik on other way.. If this don't help then you only can try factory reset, which is not 100% garant that will help, but u can try if you want.

Comment: Thank you!I uninstalled some apps to see if it makes a change.I'll comment soon if there is any change.BTW there are some some apps in play store that clear dalvik. Ex- Clear Cache app.

Comment: You can try that apps also, try clean master to clear cache, maybe will help..